# Pipe size too small for parallel sorting

Tags: c, sorting, parallel-processing, pipe

I'm implementing parallel sorting: parent process merges the sorted arrays from its children. Pipe is used for inter-process communication. I have a problem when the number of integers in the array is so large that the pipe can't pass the data. So the parent can't wait till all the integers are put onto the pipe and then start reading from it. Any ideas to solve it?

Below is the structure of my processes.

[image]

Comment: why pipes? what purpose is this for? because I would personnaly use threads

Comment: Pipes don't normally require you to wait. The reader can start reading as soon as the writer has written the first byte. Why do you think waiting is necessary?

Comment: You are doing too much copying data and not enough sorting.  There is, presumably, a lot of data.  Use shared memory across processes or, as @yakoudbz suggests, just use threads or, even better, tasks on a threadpool.